# How to convert this SQL statement to Linq for C#

Tags: c#, sql, linq, asp.net-core

I am trying to convert my simple SQL statement into Linq format for my C# application but I always seem to struggle making the conversion. I downloaded linqpad and have been playing around with it but I'm still having issues with the proper format.

My SQL statement:

```
SELECT distinct PictureCity, PictureState
FROM Website_Gallery
GROUP BY PictureCity, PictureState, PictureDate
ORDER BY PictureCity, PictureState
```

The results are ordered by PictureCity and look like this:

```
Abington    MA
Acton   MA
Acushnet    MA
Agawam  MA
Andover MA
Arlington   MA
Arlington   TX
Ashby   MA
Ashland MA
```

What I have so far in my C# application which I can't seem to get to work. (I suck at linq).

```
var Results = _context.Website_Gallery
.(g => g.PictureCity, g => g.PictureState).AsEnumerable()
.Select g
.GroupBy(g => g)
```

Comment: Why does your group by include a column you don't select?  Also if you only Group on the two columns you select then you shouldn't need the distinct, or you can keep the distinct and get rid of the group by.

Comment: Also don't use `AsEnumerable` like that as it pulls everything from the DB and does the rest of the query in memory (there are times when that is useful, but not here)

Comment: You're missing a function name on line 2 of the final snippet of code:  `.(`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like all you need is

```
var results = _context.Website_Gallery
    .OrderBy(x => x.PictureCity)
    .ThenBy(x => x.PictureState)
    .Select(x => new { x.PictureCity, x.PictureState })
    .Distinct();
```

that would be equivalent to the following SQL

```
SELECT distinct PictureCity, PictureState
FROM Website_Gallery
ORDER BY PictureCity, PictureState
```

because what you had did not need the group by

Note you can then either iterate that result in a `foreach` or tack a `ToList` to the end to materialize the query into memory.

Answer (score 0):

**SQL**

```
SELECT distinct PictureCity, PictureState
FROM Website_Gallery
ORDER BY PictureCity, PictureState
```

**Linq**

```
var Results = _context.Website_Gallery
                  .Select(g => new { g.PictureCity, g.PictureState })
                  .Orderby(p => p.PictureCity).ThenBy(p => p.PictureState)
                  .Distinct().ToList();
```

Or you can also do this

```
var Results = _context.Website_Gallery
            .GroupBy(x => new { PictureCity = x.PictureCity, PictureState = x.PictureState })
            .Select(g => new { g.Key.PictureCity, g.Key.PictureState }).Orderby(p => p.PictureCity).ThenBy(p => p.PictureState)
            .ToList();
```